# How to change a username in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I started a website which is MediaWiki based. For some reason, the username had its first letter capitalized but I don't want it capitalized (I clearly remember how I wrote it lowercased).

The Wikimedia documentation that any "Global renamer" or "Steward" can change usernames but I didn't saw such roles in my website with MediaWiki (I only have "Bureaucrat", "Sysop", "Interface-admin" and "Bot").

How to change a username in MediaWiki as a Bureaucrat?

Comment: Have you tried installing the RenameUser extension? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Renameuser

Comment: Also, usernames can't typically start with a lowercase letter in Mediawiki. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:R97c76vpuokaqby9.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try it and didn't know that datum. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I noticed that one can login with a lowercase version of the username (probably due to some JavaScript method) so it's even less a problem to have it uppercased after login. Anyone who publishes an answer might want to note that inside the answer (comments might get deleted in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RenameUser extension](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Renameuser) will allow you, as a Bureaucrat, to rename a user.

However, usernames can't typically start with a lowercase letter in Mediawiki ([more information here](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:R97c76vpuokaqby9)).

If the reason you care about the case of the first letter of your username is because of the way it displays on your User page (`http://wiki.example.com/wiki/User:yournamehere`), try adding the `{{lowercase}}` template to the content of that page. That will cause the first letter in the page's title to appear as lowercase. [More information here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Lowercase).

Comment: Hello, what is this `{{lowercase}}` syntax? An edit could help. BTW I thumbed up.